# What are rules of thumb with setting bounties?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have been recently been given the privilege to start a bounty. I have been browsing the unanswered to get some questions a chance to be answered. What are some good rules to go by to award questions bounty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the best kind of question to give a bounty is a **clearly stated** question that happens to not have a **well-written** answer yet, particularly when a good answer would be long or otherwise effortful.

Clearly stated:

- It should not be unclear what the question is; answers should not be guesses.
- The question should be easy to read. This can be fixed with editing if it's unambiguous but poorly written.

Not having a well-written answer:

- Perhaps the question has just happened to not get any answers the first time around.
- Or a good answer will require some effort (e.g. to compile information or draw diagrams).
- Or the information already exists, but the existing answers don't explain it in a way which will consistently make sense to someone who doesn't already know a lot about the subject.

But, of course, it's your own reputation to distribute as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Ben, 
Here is some information about bounties: https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=bounty.

Does that help answer your question?